# Cant align text over video

Tags: html, video, html5-video, text-alignment

I have designed a landing page but it isn't working as it should on mobile.

[Image 1 Mobile : This is what my interface looks like currently on mobile.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAd77.png)

[Image 2 Desktop : This is what it looks like on desktop.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ao69o.jpg)

**Problem:** I want the same look for mobile as for desktop.

My code is below:

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color:black;
  font-family: 'Chakra Petch', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}
 video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width:100% !important;
  z-index: 1;/*  object-fit is not supported on IE  */
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
 .container {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 200px;

}


.btn{
  background-color: #36454f !important;
  border-color: #36454f !important;
}

.btn:hover{
  background-color: #476376 !important;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Anomaly Detection Portal</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Chakra+Petch:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
<body>
 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
             
                  
                 <video autoplay muted loop>    
                  <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/368320203.sd.mp4?s=38b1bac5d627b94fb902597643461ee5f233d00a&amp;profile_id=139&amp;oauth2_token_id=57447761" type="video/mp4">                 </video>
                 
                 <div class="container">
                   <span style="font-size: 63px">Anomaly Detection Portal</span> 
                     <span>
                       <h4>
                          Use our state-of-the-art technology to find out anomalies in your traffic videos.

                       </h4>
                       <h5>
                        Our futuristic models give the maximum accuracy in more than 90% of the cases.
                       </h5>
                      </span>
                     <a class="btn btn-primary btn-md" href="login" role="button">Proceed Ahead.</a>
                 </div>
                   <!-- /.container -->
                 </div>
                 <!-- /.jumbotron -->
           
     
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Fix that first.

Comment: @Rob it is valid if you copy it into your editor.  I don't know why its like this here but it is valid.

Comment: I used [the W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#file) which is all that matters.

Comment: @Rob actually, it will be shown invalid there because as you can see I have not added the HTML tag. But you don't really need to check it because my code is executing perfectly in the built-in editor by stack overflow. I needed a solution for the position of the text and other than that my HTML is functional as it is. I thought you were referring to the opacity level but no, my code is not invlaid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use font scaling and a dynamic padding to do the job

**What I did:**

1. Changed the font-size to vw (viewport width)
2. Changed the padding to 10% (from initial 200px)
3. Added font-size to the subtitle using vw as well

If you don't like the result, you can wiggle with the values a little bit

It's not 100% the same, but it's pretty close

**Note:** you can also use a mixed approach using calc (vw and px together) to avoid not readable text, as specified in the link below

More on viewports  [here](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/)

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color:black;
  font-family: 'Chakra Petch', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}
 video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width:100% !important;
  z-index: 1;/*  object-fit is not supported on IE  */
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
 .container {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 10%;

}


.btn{
  background-color: #36454f !important;
  border-color: #36454f !important;
}

.btn:hover{
  background-color: #476376 !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Anomaly Detection Portal</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Chakra+Petch:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      </head>
    <body>
     
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                 
                      
                     <video autoplay muted loop>    
                      <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/368320203.sd.mp4?s=38b1bac5d627b94fb902597643461ee5f233d00a&amp;profile_id=139&amp;oauth2_token_id=57447761" type="video/mp4">                 </video>
                     
                     <div class="container">
                       <span style="font-size: 6vw">Anomaly Detection Portal</span> 
                         <span>
                           <h4 style="font-size: 2.5vw">
                              Use our state-of-the-art technology to find out anomalies in your traffic videos.
    
                           </h4>
                           <h5 style="font-size: 2vw">
                            Our futuristic models give the maximum accuracy in more than 90% of the cases.
                           </h5>
                          </span>
                         <a class="btn btn-primary btn-md" href="login" role="button">Proceed Ahead.</a>
                     </div>
                       <!-- /.container -->
                     </div>
                     <!-- /.jumbotron -->
               
         
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```